# freshly formated partition ext4 showing 3.4 Gib used. Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.
I have freshly formated partitions as ext4 and it shows 3.4 Gib Used.
Any idea?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely due to the data of the filesystem itself, or the system configuration of it. In just about any case, you'll see a portion of a disk or partition used by the filesystem or disk management systems. That particular bit of used storage shouldn't change in size in any noticable way.